# How to set and get json from setter/getter class?

Tags: java, json

this is my pojo class and i want make method add diary in my diary services class then how to get and set json in this method and any other way to get and set json from setter/getter class.

```
public class Dairy extends BaseEntity {

public String dairyId;
public String dairyType;
public String productName;
private List<Dairy> dataList;



public List<Dairy> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
}

public void setDataList(List<Dairy> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

public String getDairyId() {
    return dairyId;
}

public void setDairyId(String dairyId) {
    this.dairyId = dairyId;
}

public String getDairyType() {
    return dairyType;
}

public void setDairyType(String dairyType) {
    this.dairyType = dairyType;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}
```

Comment: What does "get and set json" mean?

Comment: i mean i have html form and have these field(dairyId dairyType etc). when user click on submitt button then it will throw a json i want get and set this json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hava json like this

```
product:{
          dairyId:"1",
          dairyType:"a",
          productName:"New Year 2015" 
   }
```

You should get like

```
 Dairy d=new Dairy();
```

You have to use jsonParser class.Then set value on object d.like

```
JSONObject jsonObject=getJSONObject("product");
d.setDairyId(jsonObject.getString("dairyId");
d.setDairyType(jsonObject.getString("dairyType"); 
d.setProductName(jsonObject.getString("productName");
```

To print this value you may use like:

```
 System.out.println("Name is:"+d.getProductName());
```

I hope this will help to you :)

Comment: thx yar actually i am fresher so i am totally confuse bro ..can i ask you one more question

Comment: i want define a json in my class as manually like product .can i define it in my class?

Comment: You have to download GSon library.and add it into your project. then use like Gson gson=new Gson(); gson.toJson("your Diary class object")

Comment: Gson is used to make your pojo class as json class :)